# How to download startup configuraton from a remote server on Cisco NX-OS

Tags: cisco-nx-os, tftp

I am trying to replace the startup configuration on Cisco Nexus device using a file on remote server. I tried the instructions given at this page:

[Working With Configuration Files: Downloading the Startup Configuration From a Remote Server](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_0/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide2/fun_nx-os_book/fun_config_files.html#wp1236980)

So, I tried running command `copy tftp://<server-ip-address>/nexus-startup.cfg startup-config` and got the following output with error:

```
Nexus7K01# copy tftp://172.16.38.4/nexus7k01.cfg startup-config
Enter vrf (If no input, current vrf 'default' is considered): management
Trying to connect to tftp server......
Connection to Server Established.
TFTP get operation was successful
sysmgr_copy_nvram_dest_action: src uri_type = 2 is not supported yet
Nexus7K01#
```

I tried to copy the file using all the four remote server protocol and got the same error with different URI type. `1 for FTP, 128 for SCP and 512 for SFTP`.

The device is a Cisco Nexus 7000 series device with following details:

```
Software
  BIOS:      version 3.22.0
  kickstart: version 6.1(3)
  system:    version 6.1(3)

Hardware
  cisco Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis ("Supervisor module-1X")
  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU         with 8251588 kB of memory.
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong and how can I rectify this error.

Thanks in advance!

-Varun

Comment: Is `tftp:///` a typo? It should be `tftp://` You also did not include a server in the URL.

Comment: Unfortunately, all I can add is that this works OK on my Nexus 4000 blade switch. But it runs a different version (`4.1(2)E1(1i)`) and is a different type of switch. It does warn that it is deprecated with `This command is deprecated. To obtain the same results, please use the sequence 'write erase' + 'reload' + 'copy <file> running-config' + 'copy running-config startup-config'.`

Comment: I have updated the question with complete output from the device. Moreover, when I use similar command to copy the same file to bootflash, it works fine. So, there is no typo in the command. I can't use the set of commands that you have given because I am trying to run these commands remotely by opening a CLI session and when I do "write erase", it clears out the startup configuration and on "reload", the switch starts up with an empty configuration and so I am not able to open a CLI session to the device. If there is a way to run these commands remotely from a CLI session, please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first check that you correctly have the 'nexus-startup.cfg' in your TFTP root folder, so that it's not a path issue.  I suggest this because the uri error your getting would suggest the path is not found.  Also - you'll need to address your syntax.  Following from Nx-OS contextual help:

```
 tftp:  Enter URL "tftp:[//server[:port]][/path]"
```

Also - I would try just copying it to your flash and then to startup-config after that if it's not liking the syntax you used to copy it over.

**UPDATE:**

This known issue with your NX-OS version could be related, or even the root cause:

```
CSCud05567
Symptom : Following a system switchover, copying to bootflash on the supervisor module does not work.

Conditions : This symptom might be seen under normal operating conditions for a Cisco Nexus 7000 Series device.

Workaround : None.
```

Source is [HERE](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/6_x/nx-os/release/notes/61_nx-os_release_note.html#pgfId-608687)

The good news is that this issue is only appearing from 6.1, so if you are in a position to move down to 6.0 family of NX-OS you should be good.  My personal preference anyway is to stay a family behind the latest and greatest unless there's a security patch.

Comment: The file is correctly present in the TFTP root folder as I am able the same file to the device locally on bootflash. Also, I have updated the full output of the command in the question. Please observe that GET operation was successful, but it is not able to somehow write it to the startup-configuration

Comment: Ok cool - glad to hear you can at least copy it over, and then from there you copy copy flash:blah startup-config.  My best guess Varun - is that the syntax just isn't supported in your IOS version using 'startup-config' - you should try qualifying it wish 'flash:startup-config'.

Comment: Let me know if that works and I'll update the answer to be more authoritative

Comment: It has something to do with the version of NX-OS on the device although the message is not very descriptive. For e.g., I can run the command `copy tftp://172.16.38.4/nexus7k01.cfg bootflash:startup-config` but the startup config used by the switch is present in the nvram: filesystem. So then I gave the command to copy the startup-config present in the bootflash: filesystem over to nvram: but got the below output `Nexus7K01# copy bootflash:startup-config nvram:///startup-config
This command is not supported in this release
` So, somehow the operation is not supported. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: That sucks man, I posted an update.. Let me know how you feel about that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. A system switchover would however mean that I have the switch set up with dual supervisors and a switchover happened between the active and standby due to some reason which is not the case. There is just one supervisor module in the switch. But I do believe that is an issue with the release.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is NX-OS does not support copying from remote file system directly to NVRAM:.

The work around is to first copy the file to bootflash, then to copy from boot flash to NVRAM:

ie.

```
copy ftp://user:password@server/config.cfg bootflash:///config.cfg
copy bootflash:///config.cfg startup-configuration
```

hope that helps.